# canvas with css height 100% in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, canvas, internet-explorer-9

I have a canvas with width:100% and height:100% in CSS and nothing set on the attributes. I know about the difference between the viewport size of the canvas set by attributes and the element size set regularly with css. IE9 responds well to the width:100% css but completely ignores the height. Is this a bug? What is wrong?
It works well in FF and Chrome...

Answer (score 2):

```
body {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

canvas {
   width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: it may work for a canvas directly under body, but my html is somewhat more complicated. The canvas is located in a div. I want the canvas to take the size of the div. Th containing div height is set and "behaves" ok.

Comment: @Sonia Then set `position:relative` on the containing div so that it is a positioned parent for its children. (And in the future, please post actual code—ideally a simplified, pared-down test case—so that people answering your question can do so fully.)

Comment: (minor note) When a length value in CSS is 0, it doesn't matter what the units are; the above can be rewritten more simply as `margin:0; padding:0`.